\afterpage{} causes all \begin{landscape} to gather at the end of the document
I have been having issues placing my landscape tables (using tabularx) within my document. While they generally appear in the intended location within the text, the use of the landscape environment leads to unwanted page breaks. I resorted to \afterpage{}, but instead of fixing the page breaks, it forces all of my landscape tables to be grouped together at the end of the document.
Here is my code:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}{CMU Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{CMU Serif}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{PingFang SC}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\geometry{left=30mm, top=20mm}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}{Chapter \thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\centering\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\centering\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{0.5em}{}

\onehalfspacing

\captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false, labelfont=bf, labelsep=period}

\begin{document}



\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-5]

\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
\caption{Example Table with Long Columns}
\centering
\label{tab:example}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.230\hsize}X
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.125\hsize}X
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.115\hsize}X
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.100\hsize}X
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.260\hsize}X
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.170\hsize}X }
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} & \textbf{Column 3} & \textbf{Column 4} & \textbf{Column 5} & \textbf{Column 6} \\ 
\midrule
Item 1 & A & B & C & Description 1 & Info 1 \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Item 2 & D & E & F & Description 2 & Info 2 \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Item 3 & G & H & I & Description 3 & Info 3 \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Item 4 & J & K & L & Description 4 & Info 4 \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Item 5 & M & N & O & Description 5 & Info 5 \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Item 6 & P & Q & R & Description 6 & Info 6 \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Item 7 & S & T & U & Description 7 & Info 7 \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Item 8 & V & W & X & Description 8 & Info 8 \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Item 9 & Y & Z & AA & Description 9 & Info 9 \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Item 10 & BB & CC & DD & Description 10 & Info 10 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
}

\lipsum[6-10]

\afterpage{
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Example Table with Multi-row Cells}
\label{tab:example_multirow}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.25\textwidth}X} 
\toprule
\textbf{Category} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Examples} \\ \midrule
Category 1 & Description of Category 1 & 
Example 1a \\ 
& & Example 1b \\
& & Example 1c \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Category 2 & Description of Category 2 & 
Example 2a \\
& & Example 2b \\ 
& & Example 2c \\ 
\addlinespace[5pt]
Category 3 & Description of Category 3 & 
Example 3a \\
& & Example 3b \\
& & Example 3c \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Category 4 & Description of Category 4 & 
Example 4a \\
& & Example 4b \\
& & Example 4c \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
}

\lipsum[10-15]

\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Example Table with Long Text Column}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
        >{\hsize=0.15\hsize}X
        >{\hsize=0.12\hsize}X
        >{\hsize=0.12\hsize}X
        >{\hsize=0.12\hsize}X
        >{\hsize=0.49\hsize}X }
    \toprule
    \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} & \textbf{Column 3} & \textbf{Column 4} & \textbf{Column 5} \\ 
    \midrule
    Date 1 & Item 1 & Location 1 & Place 1 & Description of Event 1 \\
    \addlinespace[5pt]
    Date 2 & Item 2 & Location 2 & Place 2 & Description of Event 2 \\
    \addlinespace[5pt]
    Date 3 & Item 3 & Location 3 & Place 3 & Description of Event 3 \\
    \addlinespace[5pt]
    Date 4 & Item 4 & Location 4 & Place 4 & Description of Event 4 \\
    \addlinespace[5pt]
    Date 5 & Item 5 & Location 5 & Place 5 & Description of Event 5 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab:example_long_text}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
}

\lipsum[15-20]


\end{document}  


And this is the output:

I believe the problem could have been caused by XeLaTeX because I previously used pdflatex and didn't notice this issue. However, I now need to use XeLaTex due to the fonts and the use of Chinese.
What could be the issue and how do I fix it?

I'd suggest you use sidewaystable from the rotating package for tables in landscape orientation. rather than landscape.

I believe pdflscape and rotating are incompatible.

afterpage has no mechanism to move anything past one page break. You have shown no example but the only way I can see afterpage material floating to the end of a document is if there are no standard pages that follow so the next page is in fact the last.

@cfr thank you! It is a big document with multiple tables, figures, etc. The strange thing is that placing them works perfectly well until I attempt to use \afterpage to avoid page breaks, which moves them to a location with other tables with \begin{landscape} until the end of a section (the document is around 200 pages long). Also it is a new issue and I can't spot what's actually changed - the only thing is an update that I installed for TexLive

@cfr and thank you, sidewaystable works! Though the preference would be to be able to rotate the landscape tables - like the pdflscape package does

@DavidCarlisle thank you for your reply! The document is at ~200 pages, and there are multiple standard pages after my landscape tables, including other pages and figures all of which are located and displayed correctly - apart from the landscape ones that tend to do a little get-together at the end of \section{} (sorry, I did say it's the end of the document). The issue only occurs when I use \afterpage, otherwise the location of the landscape pages is perfect, and sidewaystable has no issues too. Maybe there is a problem with my Tex installation?

@Octner The output is a result of code in your document. If you want help with that  code you will need to make a small example. Perhaps someone can guess from no information but I wrote \afterpage and I also wrote landscape so I know that code as well as anyone and I would not be able to even start to guess an answer.

@DavidCarlisle Thank you. I have added a new example to the original post

With your test code, I get the landscape pages 2 and 4, with text following on page 5. It looks as you'd seem to want.

@DavidCarlisle it fails with xelatex on overleaf. Was xelatex affected from the afterpage bug too?

With the new code, I get landscape pages 2 and 5.

@egreg that is the behaviour I would expect, but it is not the case for my distribution. Thank you for testing and confirming the bug!

@UlrikeFischer I can't check now, but I think yes

This seems to be the bug reported when texlive 2024 was issued https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1311.
Changes in pdftex and xetex binaries broke the afterpage package. This has been repaired and overleaf has updated pdftex in the meantime, but the xetex version they use is still the faulty one.
Report that to the overleaf support.

I am using a TexLive (MacTex) instance on my computer, while I downloaded the most recent update a few days ago. Perhaps it has not been fixed in the MacTex distribution of TexLive?

I don't have a mac, but I would assume that it was corrected too. Did you check for updates with tlmgr update --list?

Did it just now, all works!

I got confirmation from a mactex user that the example in the latex issue works correctly for him with xelatex. So if it fails for you, your binary is not uptodate.
