Unexpected behaviour in afterpage in TeXlive 2024
I just updated my TexLive from 2022 to 2024, using MacTeX.  I've noticed that the behaviour of the afterpage package has changed. Instead of putting the argument of afterpage after the page, as happened previously, it puts it at the end of the document, or end of chapter in a memoir document. The afterpage version is v1.08, which apparently was only revised in 2014, so the behaviour puzzles me. Here is a MWM, which gives different behaviour in TL 2022 and TL2024. Any explanation, or even better a solution, would be appreciated. Thanks.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\afterpage{\color{red} Now is the winter of our discontent}
\lipsum[3-7]
\end{document}


make sure you have fully updated. the original texlive 2024 pdftex and xetex binaries had a bug that broke afterpage, this is in the compiled tex source not the macro layer so updateing the tex system is the only possibility there is no tex macro fix possible

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/727222/afterpage-causes-all-beginlandscape-to-gather-at-the-end-of-the-document/727256#727256

Ah, many thanks.  That would explain it.

@DavidCarlisle close as duplicate?

@cfr I thought there was a better duplicate from the original report (that one is mostly about overleaf where "update your tex" isn't an answer, but it does link to the github issue. but I couldn't see one just now

@DavidCarlisle https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/722773/afterpage-does-not-work-with-the-newest-pdftex-version? (but comments are rather confusing.)

@cfr that's better thanks
